Is there a generalisation of Kung's method for system identification?
The Kung (1979) method of empirical system identification uses impulse response data. Van Helmont et al. (1990) published a modification to allow using step response data. Neither use the measured input signal but rather both assume an idealised excitation.
Questions:

Is there a modification that allows ramp response data to be used?
Is there a generalisation that allows the measured input data to be used to allow for arbitrary excitation signals?

The context is system identification and I am interested in model fitting approaches that do not require initial guesses or recursion.

Please don't edit your question to add answers to the question into the question.  Instead, put answers in the 'Your Answer' box below.  Thank you.

I think I have found answers:

I was able to derive a modification to use the ramp response following a similar approach to Van Helmont et al. (1990) and, more generally, it appears that this may be possible for any excitation signal that can be expressed by a recurrence relation.
A least squares solution exists using the excitation signal when its Hankel matrix has full rank (Verhaegen & Verdult, 2007).

These probably cover the vast majority of excitation signals.
